# How to set a default value against an MDC key in log4j 2?

Tags: log4j, slf4j, log4j2, mdc

As in log4j we have an option to set a default value against an MDC key like this - mdc{key:-defaultVal}

Do we have something similar in log4j 2 ?

Answer (score 6):

Looking in `MdcPatternConverter` it does not have support for default value.

There is open Jira ticket on that [Tickt](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1866)

I find that you can also use this: `${ctx:<key>:-<default_value>}`

Comment: only default value is printing but not printing the values @igreenfield

Comment: Which version you are using and how you set the MDC?

Comment: I'm using ThreadContext with spring boot log4j2 2.2.5 version but when I used double dollers like this                                                                                         
      $${ctx:<key>:-<default_value>}                                                                                  it started printing dynamic values as well with default when it's empty or null

Answer (score 4):

While there is no way to set a default with the `%X` pattern, [there are the `%equals` and `%equalsIgnoreCase` patterns](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) which can be used for something equivalent.

`%equals{%X{<key>}}{}{<default>}`

Answer (score 1):

It seems this must have changed at some point, as it is now possible to specify default values.

If you do something like `org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext.put("foo", "bar");` in your code, and then, in the log4j2 pattern, specify something like

`<Pattern>%-5p [%t] %d [$${ctx:foo:-baz}] %c{1} - %m%n</Pattern>`

You will see [bar] in the log messages generated by the same thread that the ThreadContext call was made, and you'll see [baz] in other threads.

Please note, (h/t to @Mahender Reddy Yasa in a comment above), you are able to specify `...[${ctx:foo}]...` and it will print [bar] in the correct thread, but blank in the other threads - however, and I have no idea why, if you specify `...[${ctx:foo:-baz}]...`, **it will always print [baz]** - You must use two dollar signs for it to get the correct behavior (e.g. `...[$${ctx:foo:-baz}]...`

P.S. the brackets ([]) are not necessary, this is examples from my config

Answer (score 0):

Offical Reference [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) link for Layout components.

```
X{key:-defaultVal}
```

> If the specified Key value is null, then the default value specified after the **:-** operator is output.

If no default value is specified than the empty string is output.

Comment: This is an answer for logback, but OP asked for log4j2